# Sort and bind datarow to dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

string _Code = "21";

```
        IEnumerable<DataRow> drs = GetCodes(_Code);
        foreach (DataRow items in drs)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem(items["CallingCode"].ToString(), items["CountryID"].ToString());
            ddCountry.Items.Add(li);
        }
```

//How can i sort the dropdownlist by calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help...

[Sort IEnumerable and List with property name](http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/sort-ienumerable-and-list-with-property-name/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to sort `drs` before creating the list of items...

```
var orderedDRS = drs.OrderBy(row => row["CallingCode"].ToString());
foreach (DataRow items in orderedDRS)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Where `row => row["CallingCode"].ToString()` is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397675.aspx) that selects the row's "CallingCode" as the sort key for `OrderBy`

You could use LINQ further to bind the DropDown without a `foreach` loop by [`Selecting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx#standardqueryops_topic4) out the CallingCode and CountryID values

Comment: Actually I am new to Programming, i tried to use linq but could not succed, any hints or exmple hwo i can solve this problem.  Thank you for your answer.